# Perl properly escaping string with various different quotes

Tags: perl

I am writing a script in Perl and I have a Hash of Hash which looks like this

```
my %hash = (
    "ITEM"   => {
      "cmd" => "find / \( -wholename '/home/homedir/*' -prune -o -wholename '/proc/*' -prune \) -o \( -type f -perm -0002 \) -exec ls -l '{}' ';' 2>/dev/null",
    },
```

);

Now the commands that I am using use various different quotes.  For example

```
find / \( -wholename '/home/homedir/*' -prune -o -wholename '/proc/*' -prune \) -o \( -type f -perm -0002 \) -exec ls -l '{}' ';' 2>/dev/null
```

When I run the perl script, complex commands like this won't run and throw errors such as

```
perl -e '$cmd=`find / \( -wholename '/home/homedir/*' -prune \) -o \( -type d -perm -0002 \) -exec ls -ld '{}' ';' 2>/dev/null | grep root` ; print $cmd'
```

Can't find string terminator "`" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.

Or some sory of syntax error bases commands.  I am guessing it has to do with the way Perl handles quoted strings.

How can I properly quote this strings, using the least amount of escape characters as possible. In other words.  How should I quote this string so that I can write the Hash like the one above, and not have syntax errors due to different quotes?

Comment: You can use [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) to avoid having to invoke a shell with all those nasty nested quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use single quotes alone. You need to escape them correctly using `'\''`:

```
perl -e '$cmd=`find / \( -wholename \'/home/homedir/*\' -prune \) -o \( -type d -perm -0002 \) -exec ls -ld \'{}\' \';\' 2>/dev/null | grep root` ; print $cmd'
```

some alternative Versions:

using double quotes instead of single quotes as limiter for `perl -e`:

```
perl -e "$cmd=`find / \( -wholename '/home/homedir/*' -prune \) -o \( -type d -perm -0002 \) -exec ls -ld '{}' ';' 2>/dev/null | grep root` ; print $cmd"
```

When you want to use the last version, you need to modify your hash with `q{}`, `qq{}` quoted strings:

```
my %hash = (
    "ITEM"   => {
      "cmd" => q{find / \( -wholename '/home/homedir/*' -prune -o -wholename '/proc/*' -prune \) -o \( -type f -perm -0002 \) -exec ls -l '{}' ';' 2>/dev/null},
    },
);
```

Where `q{}` is single quoted and `qq{}` is double quoted.

EDIT: you may also take a look at [`String::ShellQuote`](http://p3rl.org/String%3a%3aShellQuote).

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the single quotes on the shell level.

To demonstrate, the following is equivalent to `print "'\n";` from the command line:

```
perl -e 'print "'\''\n"'
```

Outputs:

```
'
```

Therefore you need to translate any `'` to `'\''` in your command.